# Looking for Example Embedded Linux HID Device Code

Tags: linux, embedded, usb, hid

I want to set up my embedded application as a HID device, with a separate process controlling the HID interface to allow dynamic connections to a PC.  There seems to be many people out there that have done it, but I would like to do is:

a) Understand how to configure my build (Freescale i.MX Linux using ltib) to include the USB APIs and includes in my build (ie g_hid.h).
b) Where can I find an example application which does something like move the mouse about the screen to demonstrate the operation of the HID?

Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3/Documentation/usb/gadget_hid.txt is an example of how to operate a mouse HID.

Comment: Thanx - that's a big help and has gotten me on my way.