# omap_udc.c g_hid.c hid gadget on beaglebone with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, embedded, kernel-module, hid, beagleboard

I want to use the beagleboneas as HID peripheral. I plan to do the following:

1. Discover how to build things with Ubuntu.
2. Get the kernel source (3.2.28 ?).
3. Compile omap_udc and g_hid
4. Insert those modules into the kernel
5. Compile the example from gadget_hid.txt
6. Send keyboard commands with hid_gadget_test /dev/hidg0 keyboard

*Someone had asked this question, but with angstrom on link below*:

- [omap_udc.c g_hid.c hid gadget on beagleboard with angstrom linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847391/omap-udc-c-g-hid-c-hid-gadget-on-beagleboard-with-angstrom-linux)

I followed the answer provided within the link, but build it with Ubuntu. However, this is what I get in response:

```
$ sudo insmod g_hid
insmod: error inserting './g_hid.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

Can someone tell me the reason? What am I wrong? How to address it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you've built your modules with a different compiler (or perhaps architecture?) to the kernel.

You should first work out how to build and deploy a cross-compiled kernel.   I assume you've got a ARM cross-compiler and binutils installed?  Ubuntu has packages for them, or you can use [CodeSourcery G++ Lite](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/)

A fairly reasonable set of instructions can be found [here](http://tuxthink.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/cross-compiling-linux-for-arm.html)

In essence it's:

```
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-eabi
make menuconfig
make uImage modules
make install_modules INSTALL_MOD_PATH-<target root filing system>
```

Comment: Thanks Marko,
  I got the "-1 Invalid module format" problem fixed, it was due to mismatch of kernel version on the build and the run.

Comment: But now, I ended up with "No such device" when insmod. According to someone on the net, this is due to the 3.2.23/28 kernel for beaglebone is not fully working yet. I am wondering anyone know the last working kernel with g_hid module? if so, can I have the instructions to get it?

Comment: @user1644791 another wild guess - module parameters are expected? This is very often the case with gadgets and in my experience is not documented. Time to refer to the module's source code!